# Rails3: Display messages from model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails3 app I have a method in a Model1 that creates other objects when Model1 is updated and certain conditions are met. So I have an after_update callback method in Model1 that does this work. I'd like to pass messages back to the controller to display on the page, but the flash is not available from the model.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Thing model has the regular old `attr_accessor :messages` then your controller could do this:

```
def update
  @thing = Thing.find params[:id]

  if @thing.update_attributes
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "The messages are #{@thing.messages}"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

The messages won't get saved with `@thing` but that's okay, they only need to live long enough to get into the flash notice on the next line.

Comment: I take this to mean I should add an accessor to my model and use it? Ok I did so. I added attr_accessor :messages and init'd as an array (so I can return multiple messages) in after_initialize. Then I append to it in my method and modified the display of it in my view to show all messages in the array.

So this is working, but I guess I assumed that Rails would provide something for this. Not that this is overly complicated, just seems that Rails has an answer for everything! ;-)

Comment: Forgot to say, THANKS much for answering my question.

Comment: That's the nature of rails development -- always second-guessing yourself, thinking that there must be an easier way!